# SQL: count of count in one query

Tags: sql, count, subquery, aggregate-functions

Is there a straight-forward way in SQL syntax to write this in a single query without a sub-query? And is there any chance in a performance-gain that way?

```
SELECT ProductCount, COUNT(*) as Occurence
FROM (
    SELECT OrderID, COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) as ProductCount
    FROM OrderLine
    GROUP BY OrderID
) X
GROUP BY ProductCount
ORDER BY ProductCount
```

Comment: Did you mean `COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) AS [ProductCount]`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: 1) no, there is no other way 2) no, there would be no performance gain 3) what's wrong with what you have anyway?

Comment: @Widor: yes I've edited accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What you have in your question is the recommended way to do it.
2. You are unlikely to see any performance gain from any change. This is a very common pattern which your database should cope with just fine. If it is slow, consider adding appropriate indexes.